# Conversion constructor not called where it should be

Tags: c++, constructor

Why doesen't it use any of my defined constructors during creation of newA?
I thought that non-explicit calls of copy and conversion constructors look similar, but somehow I was wrong, I guess.

```
struct B;

struct A
{
    A(){ cout<<"Default\n"<<flush; }
    A(const B&){ cout<<"Convert\n"<<flush; }
    A(const B&&){ cout<<"Convert rvalue\n"<<flush; }
    A(const A&&){ cout<<"Copy rvalue\n"<<flush; }
    A(const A&){ cout<<"Copy\n"<<flush; }
};

struct B
{   
    operator A(){ A k; return k; }
};

int main()
{

B newB;

//Prints nothing
A newA(B());

//Prints "Convert rvalue"
A newerA = A(B());

return 0;
}
```

Comment: have a look at copy ellision.

Comment: Most vexing parse, finding dupe...

Comment: @NathanOliver -- Yes! Finally! A mention of the "most vexing parse" that **really is** about the most vexing parse!

Comment: @JonnyHenly Not at all

Comment: @TheTechel there is copy elision for the conversion operator, not for the construction of ``newA`` (or ``newerA``.

Comment: @PeteBecker I know how you feel.